# PHP contact form won't display correctly. The last bit of code doesn't register as code

Tags: php, forms, contacts

For whatever reason - and yes, I am new to PHP - the PHP code won't function correctly, but also, it simply won't register as code. In this screenshot you can see that it just displays a plain text for some reason:

[image]

```
<div id="contactform">
    <?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>

<?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill the form again.";
        }
    else
    {        
        $from="From: $name<$email>/r/n Return-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("tono.nogueras@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: is the file saved as .php extension ?

Comment: ^-this, and is your server set up to pass `.php` files through the PHP interpreter?

Comment: I added more code for context. There is no .php extension file. Do I need to have my own personal server? I just want it sent to my gmail account.

Comment: PHP is server side scripting and it needs a server to be able to handle the request. So you need a server where PHP is installed.

Comment: The page that you have the above code in, what is the extension for it? .html or .php?

Comment: I have the page as a .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your mail headers are incorrect** for one thing (see fixed code below), plus as you stated in a comment I noticed now, rename your file to `.php` instead of `.html`

HTML files can run as PHP if you tell Apache to do so, but you may as well just rename it to `.php`, it's a lot simpler that way.

Use `\r\n` and not `/r/n` this will cause havoc and will not render Email addresses correctly and will show up as (for example) `Bob<email@example.com>/r/nRet` in the `from` field.

Change:

```
$from="From: $name<$email>/r/n Return-path: $email";
```

to:

```
$from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email\r\n";
```

Having the space between `/r/n` and `Return-path` did not render correctly and the server did not recognize the email as a proper Email address in having the space in there.

---

### Edit

Try this, see if you're still getting an `undefined index` error:

Sidenote: Replace `email@example.com` with your own E-mail address.

```
<div id="contactform">
    <?php
if (!isset($_POST['action']))    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>

<?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill the form again.";
        }
    else
    {        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email\r\n";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("email@example.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I fixed it as you said, but I'm still having that code show up.

Comment: You renamed it to `.php` etc. right? @AntonioNogueras and have you tried restarting everything? Web server is properly setup etc.? PHP installed and running? Plus, `mail()` needs to be setup too.

Comment: Ok, I put up on the localhost WAMP server and that got rid of the issue. I just have this popping up, and then I have a seperate issue afterwards. But how is mail() not set up? my e-mail is in there, it looks like....
http://i.imgur.com/ZVVuvjY.png

Comment: I tested your code on my (hosted) server and I did not get any error message. @AntonioNogueras as for the `mail()` setup, that is not my expertise unfortunately.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I will rewrite something for you to test out. @AntonioNogueras

Comment: that's amazing of you. I'll be here!

Comment: Reload my answer and look under **Edit** @AntonioNogueras

Comment: Awesome. That error is gone now. This is what I get next: http://i.imgur.com/zZpEc9f.png

Line 114 is this one:

mail("email@example.com", $subject, $message, $from);

Comment: As much as I would like to, that part I won't be able to help you with. You will need to go through the documentation on how to setup SMTP properly. @AntonioNogueras

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thanks so much for all your help. Mega appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a PHP-script on your local computer you have to:

1. Save your file as .php
2. Install a webserver on your computer. You may install WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and you will have everything you need.

Comment: I have the WAMP already on my computer. Do I still need to run it through that? For right now I just want it going to my gmail address.

Comment: You have to put the file (named as something.php) in the folder C:\wamp\www\. Then you should be able to run the script by go to localhost/something.php in your browser.

Comment: Ok, I put up on the localhost WAMP server, renamed it, and that got rid of the issue. I just have this popping up, and then I have a separate issue afterwards. But how is mail() not set up? My e-mail is in there, it looks like.... http://i.imgur.com/ZVVuvjY.png